# reuqure.js how to separate main module to submodules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

guys. I have some question about how can i use require.js in my project.

I have some module. For example:

obj.js

```
var MyModule = (function(){

    var myObject = function(){
       this.options = {
           foo: 'foo',
           bar: 'bar'
       };
    };

    myObject.prototype.foo = function(){
       console.log(this.options.foo);
    };

    myObject.prototype.bar = function(){
       console.log(this.options.bar);
    };

    return {
       getMyObject : function(){
          return new myObject();
       }
    }
})();
```

I haven't problems with using my object as solid. I appended to obj.js this code:

```
define(function(){
   return MyModule;
})
```

And use it in my app.js module

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl : 'lib',
    paths : {
        app:'../js/app'
    }
});

require(['app/obj'], function(MyModule){
    var someObj = MyModule.getMyObject();
    someObj.foo();
    someObj.bar();    
});
```

It's all ok. But how can i split MyModule to some submodules? For example. In module i have 1 object, its constructor and two its methods. Can i put constructor to file, for example 'mymodule.myobject.js', foo to 'mymodule.myobject.foo.js' and bar to 'mymodule.myobject.bar.js' and use it with require.js? If it's really, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way. Expect following file structure

```
- js
  -- constructors
   --- objectCostructor.js   
  -- objects
   --- objectModule.js
```

So the `objectCostructor.js` is:

```
define(function(){
   return myObject = function(){
       this.options = {
           foo: 'foo',
           bar: 'bar'
       }
    }
})
```

And `objectModule.js`

```
define(['constructors/objectCostructor'], function(Const){

    Const.prototype.foo = function(){
       console.log(this.options.foo);
    };

    Const.prototype.bar = function(){
       console.log(this.options.bar);
    };

    return {
       getMyObject : function(){
          return new Const();
       }
    }    
})
```